# Does ObjectiveC++ lambdas capture C++ variables by copy or reference?

Tags: c++11, lambda, objective-c-blocks, objective-c++

In the following function, does the ObjectiveC++ lambda function (or block) capture `str` and `sptr` by *value* or *reference*?
In other words, is the following usage valid in a multithreaded environment?

```
void local_func() { 
  std::string str;
  std::shared_ptr<int> sptr = std::make_shared<int>{42};
  [GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer fetchSavedGamesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<GKSavedGame *> * 
  _Nullable savedGames, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    // May be executed on another thread, when local_func has exited
    std::cout << str << (*sptr);
  }
};
```

Note: the is actual class/library *GKLocalPlayer* etc is not relevant to the question, I just copied the actual function I'm working with for the moment.

Comment: By value unless prefixed with `__block`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was hoping for

Comment: @H.Al-Amri: You should make that an answer.

Comment: @ViktorSehr: There is no point for an ObjC block to capture a `shared_ptr` -- capturing a `__block` variable will do the same thing underneath, with simpler syntax.